# How to resolve conflicts in Linux while Installing the packages?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have one GCP VM and I am trying to install cloud-utils package in it, but getting conflicts error.

Command:

```
 yum -y install cloud-utils
```

Error :

```
Error: gce-disk-expand conflicts with cloud-utils-growpart-0.27-10.el6.x86_64
Error: gce-disk-expand conflicts with cloud-utils-0.27-10.el6.x86_64
```

Could you please help me to resolve these conflicts.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your question does not seem to be about programming. Your question could be more appropriate on one of the many stackexchange sites, namely [Super User](https://superuser.com/about)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The error mentions that the 2 packages are in conflict. “Cloud-utils” is a package useful to manage cloud images. “Cloud-utils” includes "cloud-utils-growpart".

1 - `cloud-utils-growpart` is a utility package to expand the disk partition.

2 - `gce-disk-expand` is a GCP utility package to expand the disk partition.

You are using the same files and directories in the two packages, therefore they are in conflict. I do not know the reason why you are trying to install `cloud-utils` but I would strongly encourage you to install a utility package that is supported by the GCP.

Comment: `gce-disk-expand` is a `GCP specific` version of `cloud-utils-growpart` ...that's why the `RPM` might have them declared as "conflicting" each other.